# how to have page number in top right without section name in header?

Tags: header-footer, lyx, page-numbering

I need the page number in top right but I do not want the section show in header.. is there another way to do that?

[image]

Comment: On TeX.SX you will almost always get solutions that are really easy to deal with when using normal LaTeX, but harder to implement in the complex LyX environment. You will get LyX-specific suggestions on the mailing list `lyx-users@lists.lyx.org`

Answer (score 2):

Change the `pagestyle` in your preamble with either `fncyhdr` or `titleps`. Example with titleps:

```
\usepackage{titleps}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\headrule %% if you want a rule
\sethead[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: how to use these packages? I'm a new user of lyx..please help me so I just copy it and paste it in preamble..I tried to paste this example but it did not work

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: @JejeZzz note that in LyX, you can go to Document > Settings > Page Layout and set "Page style" to "fancy" in order to load the fancyhdr package. After you set that, copy the rest (i.e. everything except the first line) of Bernard's proposed code into Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble. LyX does not have built-in support for the "titleps" package, but this can of course be loaded manually in the preamble.

Comment: nothing did work

Comment: I had forgotten a pair of braces in `pagestyle{plain}. Also, check if the code doesn't load `fancyhdr` in addition to `titleps` – this would result in a conflict.

Comment: @JejeZzz In the future, please give more details. Phrases like "nothing did work" could be improved. What didn't work (compiling?)? Did you get an error? What was it?